# Replace empty fields with 0 in scrapy script

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am editing an old scrapy script.  For some pages, "Bathrooms" field does not exist.  If it does not exist, I want to input a "0".

I can post process with pandas but now I want to achieve this within the scrapy script.

I try this, but get error..

town.py", line 88
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
bathrooms_txt = response.xpath(".//dt[contains(text(), 'Bathrooms')]/following-sibling::dd/text()").extract_first()
if bathrooms_txt == "":
    bathrooms = "0"
    else:
        bathrooms = bathrooms_txt
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: The indentation is off. The `else` and `except` blocks need to be at the `if`-block level

Comment: Plus, `if` statements do not support `except` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be messing up your try statement.

Did you mean to put:

```py
bathrooms_txt = response.xpath(".//dt[contains(text(), 'Bathrooms')]/following-sibling::dd/text()").extract_first()
try:
    if bathrooms_txt == "":
       bathrooms = "0"
    else:
       bathrooms = bathrooms_txt
except:
   pass
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I received no errors, however the "if" statement did not work correctly.  The "else:" statement did work correctly.

Comment: To clarify, I am looking up home for sale data. When I scrape land for sale, there is no "Bathrooms" data.  So I need to place a 0 in that spot. Currently the script is leaving it blank.

Sorry iam not great with this.

Comment: If the else-statement worked correctly, I would check to see what bathrooms_txt actually outputs. Try printing its value as well as checking its type (`type(bathrooms_txt)`). It might not be an empty string. Try checking its length (`len(bathrooms_txt)`) as well if it is a blank string

Comment: My point is that you might be checking for the wrong thing in the if-statement (i.e. not `""`)

Answer (score 0):

edit piplines.py

```py
 def process_item(self, item, spider):
     if item.get('bathrooms_txt') is none:
         item['bathrooms_txt'] = "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

`extract_first` method have `default` argument you can use for this cases:

```
value = response.xpath("selector").extract_first(default="0")
```

or:

```
value = response.xpath("selector").extract_first("0")
```